# When I hide a textbox in a Table, is it expected that the table reformats the space?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a input type=text in a table (in a TD actually)
When a user clicks a checkbox, the input is hidden with Jquery (via the hide method)
This makes the style of the input to "display:none;"

So far so good.
Now, when that has happened, the row where the cell is in is shrunk (the height is lowered) because the only thing left in the row is a `<span>`, which height is lower than the input height.
The net result of this is that the row gets smaller, and when you click the checkbox again the input re-appears and the row gets larger.

That doesn't look so nice, so I wondered if there was a way to prevent this?

And second: is this the way it should work (the table resizing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) :hidden instead of `hide()`, it doesn't remove element from document flow.

```
$(' ... ').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Excellent! Didn't find a Jquery function to do it though, but me=happy